# What term do you use for an impulsive reaction?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, idiom-requests

I keep thinking about it and I can't remember a certain phrase. It's not 'whim' but more like,

> I didn't mean to laugh it's just my _______ reaction

or

> I didn't mean to hit you it was just my _____ reaction.

I think it's "something" reaction, I just can't really remember it and it's bothering me.

Hope I'm explaining myself right. Thanks

Comment: Instinct? Instinctive?

Comment: Apparently you didn't care for *impulsive*, but did you already discount all its many synonyms  shown by https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/impulsive?

Comment: Trumpian suggests itself.

Comment: "It's just a *reflex*?"

Comment: *gut*? *first*? *spontaneous*? Please [edit] your post to explain what research you've done and why each of the words you've already looked at doesn't suit. See [ask] for further guidance. :-)

Answer (score 7):

It's just my [**kneejerk reaction**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/knee-jerk) perhaps.

> Informal. reacting according to a certain habitual manner; unthinking:
>   a knee-jerk liberal.

Synonyms: ***involuntary***, ***unthinking***, ***spontaneous***.
 Perhaps also ***affective*** or ***compulsive***.

Comment: What I like about this is that when you tap the knee with the hammer, there's no stopping and thinking.  The knee jerks as an automatic reaction (if it's hit the right way).

Answer (score 2):

> **gut reaction**

See: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gut-reaction):

> a reaction to a situation derived from a person's instinct and experience

But I admit this is more appropriate to a mental response than a physical one.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen not to accept "casual, inadvertent", what would you say about "a spur-of-the-moment reaction"? Sorry, I didn't mean to hit you. My reaction was just on the spur of the moment.